# Robocopy : Use the monitor function for extra actions

Tags: python, robocopy

So I'm using the MON:1 parameters with robocopy, but I want to use use this parameter for extra actions.

it is possible when there where no changes detected for 20 minutes that I start an extra script?

This is the code that I use now : `os.system("robocopy " + "\"" + source + "\"" + " \"" + destination + "\"" + " /E /Z /MON:1/R:10/W:5")`

Answer (score 0):

[Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) has the option to monitor the source directory, and copy over any files that have changes. You can specify how many changes in the directory must occur before copying (`/mon n` where `n` is the number of changes) so try setting it to (/`mon 0` and how long to wait before rescanning (`/mot t` where `t` is the time to wait in minutes).
As you would like to monitor a folder in a frequency of 20mins, so try `/mot 20`.Then add your next script.

Comment: Hi, yes i added that parameter, but I want to do the next thing; IF no changes have been noticed in 20 minutes than run different script

Comment: After an action is executed, what you can do is, make a back up script. see:https://caughtinpixels.com/how-to-create-a-backup-script-using-robocopy/